SQL insert from different rows
How can I insert all the rows from score_table into viewing_table? I can't find any solution to my problem. Is it possible?
here is the table i want to do
Table_sample
INSERT INTO viewing_table (student_number, Running1, Running2, Running3, Swimming1, Swimming2, Swimming3)
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        student_number,
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '1' AND student_number = student_number),
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '2' AND student_number = student_number),
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '3' AND student_number = student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '1' AND student_number = student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '2' AND student_number = student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table 
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '3' AND student_number = student_number), 
    FROM 
        score_table

I'm using pgAdmin 4 Query Editor

What happens when you execute this query?

uh, the inner query (that (SELECT score FROM score_table WHERE item = 'Running' AND...) returns multiple rows right?

yes it returns multiple rows.. the problem lies on student_number = student_number how can i use the student_number from the SELECT to used on second select

Either make sure each subquery never returns more than one row. Or LEFT JOIN them instead.

You should 'alias' the tables properly in the FROM clause:
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        student_number,
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b 
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '1' AND a.student_number = b.student_number),
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '2' AND a.student_number = b.student_number),
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b
         WHERE item = 'Running' AND item_id = '3' AND a.student_number = b.student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '1' AND a.student_number = b.student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '2' AND a.student_number = b.student_number), 
        (SELECT score FROM score_table b
         WHERE item = 'Swimming' AND item_id = '3' AND a.student_number = b.student_number)
    FROM 
        score_table a

Otherwise you are saying student_number = student_number, which is always true and the subquery returns all rows for that student_number
